# PowerMock / Mockito casting mocked objects not working

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, mockito, powermock

I initialize in my test:

```
this.sessionMock = mock(Session.class);
```

And in the method under test the line:

```
((MySession)session).setRecordLimits(recordLimits)
```

gives me:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
 org.hibernate.Session$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$8561a329 
 cannot be cast to myApp.MySession
```

The class:

```
public class MySession extends AbstractSessionImpl implements EventSource
```

Is it a problem of Mockito / Powermock or is it a Problem with Hibernate? And is there any fix for this?

Comment: Try _this.sessionMock = mock(MySession.class);_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By telling Mockito/Powermock that you want to mock `Session`, it has no way to know the class you want to mock is actually `MySession`.

Due to your code actually depends on a `MySession`, you should do

```
this.sessionMock = mock(MySession.class);
```

instead

Comment: it works, but i would be more happy if i could tell Mockito/Powermock how to cast properly.

Comment: This is the way.  Mockito/Powermock has nothing to do with the casting action.  Casting is not working because the mock is not bearing the type that you are looking for.  Hence when you are creating the mock, you need to tell it the proper type (by passing in the correct class to mock) the mock should bear.

Comment: Adrian Shum - I tried your answer, but it didn't work for me. Do you have any idea what might have caused it?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? The resulting mock is not implementing the type you passed in? Exception? you gotta give more detail

Comment: Some possible problems: 1. The type you passed in is a concrete class (instead of interface) and you are using version of Mockito that is too old (it support built-in concrete class mocking at somewhere like 1.7)  2. The type you passed in is a final class 3. You simply have a typo/wrong import so that the you are not mocking what you suppose to mock :P